# How to access the <p> tag next to <p class="bold"> Last Statement:</p>

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```html
<p class="bold">Date of Execution:  </p>
<p>February 6, 2020</p>
<p class="bold"> Offender:</p>
<p>Ochoa, Abel Revill #999450</p>
<p class="bold"> Last Statement:</p>
<p>Yes sir. I  would like to thank God, my dad, my Lord Jesus savior for saving me and changing  my life. I want to apologize to my in-laws for causing all this emotional pain.  I love y’all and consider y’all my sisters I never had. I want to thank you for  forgiving me. Thank you warden. </p>
<p> </p>
```

How can i access the second last paragraph tag? (the one before the last empty tag)

```html
para = soup('p')
    for item in para:
        string = str(item)
        if '<p class="bold"> Last Statement:</p>' not in string: continue
        print(string)
```

This is my code, what should be my next step?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [43]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [44]: a = """<p class="bold">Date of Execution:  </p>
    ...: <p>February 6, 2020</p>
    ...: <p class="bold"> Offender:</p>
    ...: <p>Ochoa, Abel Revill #999450</p>
    ...: <p class="bold"> Last Statement:</p>
    ...: <p>Yes sir. I  would like to thank God, my dad, my Lord Jesus savior for saving me and changing  my life. I w
    ...: ant to apologize to my in-laws for causing all this emotional pain.  I love y’all and consider y’all my siste
    ...: rs I never had. I want to thank you for  forgiving me. Thank you warden. </p>
    ...: <p> </p>"""

In [45]: soup = BeautifulSoup(a,"lxml")

In [46]: soup.find_all("p")[-2].text.strip()
Out[46]: 'Yes sir. I  would like to thank God, my dad, my Lord Jesus savior for saving me and changing  my life. I want to apologize to my in-laws for causing all this emotional pain.  I love y’all and consider y’all my sisters I never had. I want to thank you for  forgiving me. Thank you warden.'
In [49]: soup.find_all("p")[-3].text.strip() + ": " + soup.find_all("p")[-2].text.strip()
Out[49]: 'Last Statement:: Yes sir. I  would like to thank God, my dad, my Lord Jesus savior for saving me and changing  my life. I want to apologize to my in-laws for causing all this emotional pain.  I love y’all and consider y’all my sisters I never had. I want to thank you for  forgiving me. Thank you warden.'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for `<p>` tag with text that contains "Last Statement" and then get next`<p>` tag.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<p class="bold">Date of Execution:  </p>
<p>February 6, 2020</p>
<p class="bold"> Offender:</p>
<p>Ochoa, Abel Revill #999450</p>
<p class="bold"> Last Statement:</p>
<p>Yes sir. I  would like to thank God, my dad, my Lord Jesus savior for saving me and changing  my life. I want to apologize to my in-laws for causing all this emotional pain.  I love y’all and consider y’all my sisters I never had. I want to thank you for  forgiving me. Thank you warden. </p>
<p> </p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
p = soup.select_one('p.bold:contains("Last Statement") + p')
print(p.text)
```

Prints:

```
Yes sir. I  would like to thank God, my dad, my Lord Jesus savior for saving me and changing  my life. I want to apologize to my in-laws for causing all this emotional pain.  I love y’all and consider y’all my sisters I never had. I want to thank you for  forgiving me. Thank you warden.
```